# Loopback lb-services.js Docular Error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loopback

I´m trying to generate the docs for the lb-services.js file of the Loopback Angular SDK. Howerver I´m getting this weird error when running `grunt`.

```
Running "docular" task                                                                                                                                      
(node:18260) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.  
(node:18260) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.  
Loading individual files for gid: Base                                                                                                                      
Loading individual files for gid: loopback                                                                                                                  
Loading individual files for gid: lbServices                                                                                                                
Parsing files for gid:  Base                                                                                                                                
Parsing files for gid:  loopback                                                                                                                            
Parsing files for gid:  lbServices                                                                                                                          
Backfilling file data for gid:  Base                                                                                                                        
Backfilling file data for gid:  loopback                                                                                                                    
Backfilling file data for gid:  lbServices                                                                                                                  
Creating docs from for gid:  Base                                                                                                                           
Creating docs from for gid:  loopback                                                                                                                       
Creating docs from for gid:  lbServices                                                                                                                     
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'docular_generated\sources\lb-services.js'             
  at Error (native)                                                                                                                                         
  at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)                                                                                                                      
  at copyFileSync (node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-file-sync.js:21:16)                    
  at Object.copySync (node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-sync.js:32:7)                       
  at .<anonymous> (node_modules\docular\lib\scripts\core\generator.js:132:25)                      
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)                                                                                             
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)                                                                                      
  at process.fallback (C:\Users\pablo\Dropbox\Nozzmo\Reuniones\exeboard\backend\node_modules\async-listener\index.js:450:15)                                
From previous event:                                                                                                                                        
  at Group.extend.exportDocFiles (node_modules\docular\lib\scripts\core\generator.js:123:25)       
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)                                                                                             
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)                                                                                      
  at process.fallback (node_modules\async-listener\index.js:450:15)                                
{ Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'docular_generated\sources\lb-services.js'           
  at Error (native)                                                                                                                                         
  at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)                                                                                                                      
  at copyFileSync (node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-file-sync.js:21:16)                    
  at Object.copySync (node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-sync.js:32:7)                       
  at .<anonymous> (node_modules\docular\lib\scripts\core\generator.js:132:25)                      
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)                                                                                             
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)                                                                                      
  at process.fallback (node_modules\async-listener\index.js:450:15)                                
From previous event:                                                                                                                                        
  at Group.extend.exportDocFiles (node_modules\docular\lib\scripts\core\generator.js:123:25)       
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)                                                                                             
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)                                                                                      
  at process.fallback (node_modules\async-listener\index.js:450:15)                                
  errno: -4048,                                                                                                                                             
  code: 'EPERM',                                                                                                                                            
  syscall: 'open',                                                                                                                                          
  path: 'docular_generated\\sources\\lb-services.js' }                                     
Warning: Task "docular" failed. Use --force to continue.                                                                                                    

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I´m using Windows 10 and Node v6.0.0. The gruntfile just contains the

'loopback_sdk_angular', 'docular', 
  'uglify'

taks.

Can anyone help me find the cause of this error?